# Unhandled promise rejection despite catching the promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I don't understand... Is it me or is this a bug in node?

This is fine as expected:

```
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject('timeout'), 1000);
});
a.catch(console.log);
```

And this is throwing a warning:

```
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject('timeout'), 1000);
});
a.then(console.log);
a.catch(console.log);
```

I get

```
timeout
(node:40463) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): timeout
(node:40463) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Have you tried not separating it? `a.then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: you could also do a try catch instead...

Comment: Is that closure with setTimeout opened and closes correctly. Does it need curly brackets?

Comment: a.then(...) produces a new promise, one that you haven't attached a catch to.

Comment: Hum... But in this case, why `a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(reject,0);});
a.then(console.log).catch(() => console.log('catched'));` would not generate an unhandled rejection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `.then(...)` with a promise returns a new promise (that's called [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)). Therefore, when you do something like:

```
a.then(console.log); // line 1 creates a new promise "b"
a.catch(console.log); // line 2 handles rejection on promise "a"
```

where `a` is your initial promise, you're creating a new promise on line 1 (one that is not `a` anymore. let's call it 
`b`). So even though you're using `.catch(...)` with `a`, you're not handling the rejection on `b`, which explains the message you're seeing on console.

To avoid this message, you should add a `.catch(...)` to this new promise `b`, on line 1

Comment: Asked here if they would be willing to make `.finally` promises stop causing unhandled rejections: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28636

Answer (score 5):

Annotated and slightly modified source:

```
// promise A is created
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject('timeout'), 1000);
});

// promise A is chained with .then()
// means new promise is created
// and only resolve catched here
const aThenPromise = a.then(console.log);

// promise A is chained with .catch()
// means new promise is created
// and only reject catched here
const aCatchPromise = a.catch(console.log);

// aThenPromise !== aCatchPromise
```

When promise `a` is rejected:

- `aCatchPromise` works as expected, and `timeout` is logged to console
- `aThenPromise` does nothing, as it works only with `resolve()`, and reject is passed through it, and not handled **because it is different Promise**. This leads to `UnhandledRejection`

You need to add catch to `aThenPromise`,

One possible option is `a.then(console.log).catch(console.log)` this will handle rejection passed through `.then`

Comment: Nice detailed explanation. Thanks.